# Maven dependency gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am working in a Maven project (Java, using `pom.xml` files), where I need to use the `FastMath` library (part of the Apache commons `math3` library).

The top level library on which I am working finds FastMath without problems. However, one of the dependencies (a local .jar that I installed so that it appears in the .m2/repository) also needs FastMath, but it gives the NoSuchMethodError message.

Installed the .jar as follows:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/me/Libraries/A.jar -DgroupId=x.y -DartifactId=y -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Included it in the pom.xml file as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>x.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>y</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It compiles without problems, the error only occurs when I attempt to run/debug.

Thanks, Michiel

Answer (score 0):

This type of maven repository is not available in central repository also
.to resolve that one try to add manulaly dependencies to project http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=x.y